# How to properly test a function that fill a combobox from a database

Tags: python, sqlite, testing, pyqt5, qcombobox

I am using PyQt5 for my IHM. It is a form. I need to fill some combobox with datas in a database.

For the moment, it's in a class name Ui_dialog. I have two questions.

1. How can I properly make an unit test on these function? I do not really know how to start my tests sometimes.
2. Does I need to use the resources of my project (database, xmls, etc) or I need to make some specials data for my test in order cover all possible cases?

```py
def fill_combobox_from_database(self,name_of_table,name_of_field,combobox):
    connexion = sqlite3.connect(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))+"\\"+Ui_dialog.NAME_DB)
    cursor = connexion.cursor()
    try:
        request = "select {0} from {1}".format(name_of_field,name_of_table)
        results = cursor.execute(request)
        for row in results:
            combobox.addItem(row[0])
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Answer (score 0):

For the start, you should move that cursor creation to separate function where it should be tested (below I named it `get_cursor`).

Then you should mock the `execute` method. I suggest using [pytest](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/) and [pytest-mock](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-mock/).

```
def test_fill_combobox_from_database_calls_execute(mocker):   
    mocked = mocker.patch("my_module.get_cursor")
    TABLE = "foo"
    FIELD = "bar"
    mocked_combo = mocker.MagicMock()
    REQUEST = "select {0} from {1}".format(FIELD, TABLE)
    MyApp().fill_combobox_from_database(TABLE, FIELD, mocked_combo)
    mocked.return_value.execute.assert_called_once()
    mocked.return_value.execute.assert_called_with(REQUEST)
```

After that you should check if combobox's additem method is called with correct arguments:

```
def test_fill_combobox_from_database_calls_combobox_additem(mocker):   
    SAMPLE = [("foo",), ("bar",), ("foobar",)]
    mocked_cursor = mocker.patch("my_module.get_cursor")
    mocked_cursor.return_value.execute.return_value = SAMPLE
    TABLE = "foo"
    FIELD = "bar"
    mocked_combo = mocker.MagicMock()
    REQUEST = "select {0} from {1}".format(FIELD, TABLE)
    MyApp().fill_combobox_from_database(TABLE, FIELD, mocked_combo)
    for item in SAMPLE:
        calls = [mocker.call(item[0])]
        mocked_combo.addItem.assert_has_calls(calls, any_order=True)
```

and also you should test the exception:

```
def test_fill_combobox_from_database_on_exception(mocker):   
    mocked_exception = Exception()
    mocker.patch("my_module.get_cursor")
    mocked_cursor.return_value.execute.side_effect = mocked_exception
    mocked = mocker.patch("my_module.print")
    MyApp().fill_combobox_from_database("foo", "bar", mocker.MagicMock())
    mocked.assert_called_once()
    mocked.assert_called_with(mocked_exception)
```

Comment: Thanks you for helping me with the test ! Yesterday I tried to use mock for testing as you suggest to set your example. I guess I have to learn a little bit more about how it's work, how to mock method. Your answer has been a big help for me to know where I need to search. Thanks you!

Answer (score 0):

First yes if you are wanting to build a true Functional Test you should build something that tests the full gambit of the function you are testing.  It should include good data, borderline data, bad data and/or basically anything and everything you think it might receive from its source.

I do this all the time when working with the GUI but first you have to remember that in MVC methodology-ish (which is what you ought to be using) the front-end is completely divorced from the back-end via a call to the middle-tier so with that said all you have to do is create a dummy function that mimics what you get back from that call to your Middle-Tier that you plan on making.

As such your function should involve calling a function that simply makes a call such as

```
def fill_combobox(self,combobox):    
    results = GetThisRecSet(parameter(s))

    for row in results:
        combobox.addItem(row[0])
```

Without any reference to SQL or whatever that is integral to the back-end.  Now the parameter(s) might be the FieldName you need or a List of FieldNames but these do not even need to be the FieldNames found in the database and you should definitely not be referencing a table.  The front-end (as stated) should be basically totally ignorant of the back-end it just sends what it wants and the Middle-Tier translates that and gets whatever from the Back-end then gives that to the Front-end in the format it is expecting regardless of what that format is.

Typically I pass a recordset and this is sufficient but maybe you do not want to do that and instead want to pass something else to the GUI.  Whatever this is clearly define what it will be then create your dummy function accordingly. Then when it comes time to hook things up you simply change the dummy function to get the data from the actual source and put that data into the format you want passed to the GUI.  This also can be used as a functional test by supplying the data you want the GUI to work with and this way you know exactly what its getting and its just a matter of plug-in-play -- unhook the real Class and substitute the functional testing Class for they both have the same set of hooks just the test one uses static values or semi-static values or whatever is determined needs to be made type functions that can then be used time and time again to check if anything was broken when changes were made to the front-end.

For instance (as stated) I often pass recordsets (when applicable) as such here is a dummy class function that I might create to do just that.

```
class MyDatabase:
    # This will handle everything pertinent to the Database
    def __init__(self,pathfilename):
        self.__dbasePathName = pathfilename

    def GetData(self):
        DataRecSet = [
            {'Field1':'Value1-1', 'Field2':'Value1-2'} ,
            {'Field1':'Value2-1', 'Field2':'Value2-2'} ,
            {'Field1':'Value3-1', 'Field2':'Value3-2'}
            ]

        return DataRecSet
```

Then all I have to do is instantiate MyDatabase like I would normally and make the calls to these dummy functions until I am ready to plug it into the actual back-end.  Conversely I can test the back-end in a similar manner from the Middle-Tier without ever being concerned about how that data is going to be displayed.

As a final note I tend to build these Functional Test Classes as I go as I need to be able to Test various pieces of the GUI as I am building it then once I am done I clean it up a little and save it as my actual Functional Test Class.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer and your help with my conception. I "tried" to use MVC pattern, but it's true that sometimes by coding I forget and do not does my decomposition. Thanks you also for helping me to understand what I need to test.